# Positive harmonic functions on nilpotent groups & Random walk on groups with a finite number of generators

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory, harmonic-functions, paper-request

I want to read the following papers in the English version which I could not find anywhere (the only papers I can get are the Russian versions). Kindly help me out.

Gregory A. Margulis, Positive harmonic functions on nilpotent groups. Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 166 (1966), 1054–1057 (Russian); English translation in: Soviet Math. Dokl. 7 (1966),

Dynkin, E. B.; Maljutov, M. B.
Random walk on groups with a finite number of generators. (Russian)
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 137 1961 1042–1045.

I do apologize for asking this here as this is not the right platform. I have checked at Mathscinet but these are not available there. So I could not think of any better way to find it. If I can get any one these two I will be really grateful.

Comment: The papers are in Russian here: [Dynkin & Malyutov 1961](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=24855&option_lang=eng) and [Margulis 1966](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=32087&option_lang=eng). They are short, and mostly contain formulas, so Google translate (or [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator)) will give you a very easily readable English version.

Answer (score 2):

About Margulis' paper, the contents of his article are very well explained in Section 25 of Woess' book Random walks on infinite graphs and groups (available online). One of the most important result of Margulis' paper is that positive harmonic functions on finitely generated nilpotent groups are constant on left cosets of the commutator subgroup. This is Corollary 25.9 in Woess' book.

In the same book, the results of Dynkin and Malyutov are considered (for instance in the preface). Their results about the integral representation of harmonic functions is proved (with more generality) in Section 26.A.

Comment: actually reading Theorem 25.8 and Corollary 25.9 in Woess book, i'm not sure anymore if the hypothesis "finitely generated" is required for this specific result from Margulis...? Step 2 in Theorem 25.8 seems to imply this fact (without use of step 3). If this is correct, then the result holds for  a locally nilpotent group (which is not necessarily nilpotent).

Comment: @ARG You're right, but I do not remember the exact assumptions required on the graph X. So I kept the word finitely generated in the answer. If you look at the proof of Corollary 25.9, the results of Theorem 25.8 are applied to the Cayley graph of N. I don't know if Cayley grphs with inifinitely many generators are considered. Thank you for your comments !

Comment: Section 24 only requires a Markov chain on a discrete set $X$, but at the beginning of section 25 $d(x,y)$ appears (which requires a metric on $X$). It could be a long chase before making sure this works... Thanks for the answer!